# JQUERY DataTable FnServer Data not called on second time event(Button Click)

Tags: jquery, datatables

Am using JQUERY DataTable and am loading Data using fnserverdata Ajax calls.

When i click serach button for first time

```
'fnServerData':function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
    console.log("Called");
    $.ajax({
    .
    .
    .
    })
```

my `console is getting logged for first time`.

Second time if i click search '`fnServerData`' is not getting called and result is shown using my first time data.

My console in above is not logged in `fnServerData` as the function is not called

Am i missing any thing or did any one faced similar issues ?

Work around will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a fix for this ?

Comment: did you find solution?? even i am facing same issue..

Comment: Adding "destroy: true" inside dataTable method solved this issue.

Answer (score 2):

For that you have to destroy datatable, and recreate each time.

```
function dataTableView()
{
   $('#tableID').dataTable({
   "bDestroy": true
   });
}
```

thanks.